# laravel json data listing

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm getting json data but I can't list it in datatable

Controller File

```
 public function index()
{
      $data = Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    return view('frontend.default.index', ['data'=> $data->json()]);
}
```

View File

```
      <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            <tr>
                <td>
                {{$value->title}} // not working
               </td>
                <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: The content in `$data` is not an object. You can check what is inside `$data` with the function `dd()`, for example in the controller: `  $data = Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');  dd($data);` ,  And it will print in the browser what is the content. It looks like it's an array of strings, but you have to check first

Comment: And [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question, so someone can give you a proper answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you pull from json comes as an array. You are trying to print as an object while you print.

**Solution**

```
 @foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>
            {{$value['title']}} // not working
           </td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you use JSON data types for ajax since they cannot pass array or object data without JSON but when you are directly printing the value in the view then you do not need to convert the data to  JSON. here is how you can use it.

```
    public function index()
{

      $data = Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
//check if data is being received
    if(!$data)
      return back()->with('error', 'no data received');
    return view('frontend.default.index', compact('data'));

}
```

and in the front end......

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            <tr>
                <td>
                {{$value->title}}
               </td>
                <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

or

```
 <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            <tr>
                <td>
                {{$value['title']}}
               </td>
                <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```